How to search for FirstName, MiddleName and LastName in MySql
I have a stored procedure that is used for customer search.
Curently I am having issues geeting search results when the MiddleName is ommitted.
Below is a breakdown of the error
if a customer name have middlename, e.g. James Mark Luke
and I search with James Luke, the record does not appear


SELECT c.Id,
    c.UserId,
    c.FirstName,
    c.MiddleName,
    c.LastName,
    c.Gender,
    c.DateOfBirth,
    c.EmailAddress,
    c.MobileNumber,
    c.Status,
    c.CreatedOn,
    c.SignUpType,
    c.HolderTier,
    c.WalletNumber
FROM User c
WHERE    c.isdeleted = 0
  AND      (
                    p_search IS NULL
           OR       CONCAT_WS(' ', c.firstname, c.middlename, c.lastname) LIKE CONCAT('%', TRIM(COALESCE(p_search, '')), '%')
           OR       c.mobilenumber LIKE CONCAT('%', TRIM(COALESCE(p_search, '')), '%')
           OR       c.bvn LIKE CONCAT('%', TRIM(COALESCE(p_search, '')), '%')
           OR       c.emailaddress LIKE CONCAT('%', TRIM(COALESCE(p_search, '')), '%'))
  AND      (
                    p_careofficer IS NULL
           OR       c.careofficer = p_careofficer)
  AND      (
                    p_gender IS NULL
           OR       c.gender = p_gender)
  AND      (
                    p_status IS NULL
           OR       c.status = p_status)
  AND      (
                    p_holdertier IS NULL
           OR       c.holdertier = p_holdertier)
  AND      (
                    p_signuptype IS NULL
           OR       c.signuptype = p_signuptype)
  AND      (
                    p_datefrom IS NULL
           OR       c.createdon BETWEEN p_datefrom AND      p_dateto )
ORDER BY c.CreatedOn DESC
LIMIT p_pagesize OFFSET page_offset;
END

I have tried using

IFNULL(MiddleName, '')
COALESCE(MiddleName)

Both have not yielded the much expected result.
Previously, I was using FullText Search(FTS) but that was completely overhauled.

use 2 OR in the WHERE like:         OR CONCAT_WS(' ', c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName) LIKE CONCAT('%', TRIM(COALESCE(p_search, '')), '%')
OR         OR CONCAT_WS(' ', c.FirstName, c.LastName) LIKE CONCAT('%', TRIM(COALESCE(p_search, '')), '%')

I'd say your MiddleName is '' not NULL? Is that so? In that case use NULLIF(TRIM(MiddleName), '') in your CONCAT_WS. If MiddleName is '' you get two spaces between first and last name, which doesn't compare. You may want to add other protection against double spaces, also in the search term. If your MySQL supports it:  REGEXP_REPLACE(p_search, '[[:space:]]+', ' ')

@Roemer
Thanks for the update.
I will try the NULLIF(TRIM(MiddleName).
However, I will have to look at REGEXP_REPLACE much later

@BerndBuffen
Your solution worked well for me with a slight issue with space ''

@AzubuikeOkolie Use Bernd Buffen's approach, mine only solves the double spaces problem, it doesn't enable you to skip the Middle name at all.

@BerndBuffen he's approach dies work with the exception of the space issue. My PC is bad  ATM moment but once fixed I'll combine your approach of the nullif to his

you can also tested like this sample:
the table
SELECT *
FROM ratingtbl;

1   James   Mark    Luke
2   James   NULL    Luke
3   Peter   NULL    Miller
4   Peter   Mark    Miller

the query
SET @searchval:="James mark";

SELECT *
FROM ratingtbl
WHERE
CASE length(@searchval) - length(REPLACE(@searchval,' ',''))
-- only 1 arguent - can be in first, mid or lastname
WHEN 0 THEN IF(@searchval IN ( firstname,midname,lastname),TRUE,FALSE)

-- two args - can be in (first,mid) or (first,last) or (mid,last)
WHEN 1 THEN IF(@searchval IN ( CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname,midname),CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname,lastname),CONCAT_WS(' ',midname,lastname) ),TRUE,FALSE)

-- three args - must be IN FIRST mid AND LAST
WHEN 2 THEN IF(@searchval = CONCAT_WS(' ',firstname,midname,lastname),TRUE,FALSE)

-- four AND more are NOT valid FOR NAMES
ELSE FALSE
END;

the result
1   James   Mark    Luke

remove the comments and change the varnames to you fields and
add your rest of the WHERE (OR...)
